# Динамическое создание формы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Пытаюсь создать форму:

```js
$("#b_0").html('<form>');
$("#b_1").html('<input id="dstr" type="hidden" value="">');
$("#b_2").html('<input id="kstr" type="hidden" value="">');
$("#b_3").html('<input type="hidden" id="mta" value = ""/>');
$("#b_4").html('</form>');
```

```html
<div id="b_0"></div>
<div id="b_1"></div>
<div id="b_2"></div>
<div id="b_3"></div>    
<div id="b_4"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

На выходе получаю:

```
<div id="b_0">
    <form></form>
</div>
```

А `<div id="b_4"></div>` - пустой. Как можно добавить `<form>` без закрывания?

Comment: Вы хотите разорвать форму между двумя дивами. Это не правильно.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev если уж ломать созданный мною рабочий сниппет, то и `<script src="..."></script>` можно убрать. Непонятно только что не так было со сниппетом...

Comment: Он ничего не отображал при выполнении. Так как видимого результата нет, ценность в его запуске сомнительная.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev визуальных красивостей, конечно, не было, но зато  при инспекции четко было видно, что, например, `<div id="b_0">` действительно имеет внутри себя `<form></form>`. Но да ладно.

Comment: Возможно, я был не прав. Вы можете отменить мою правку, воспользовавшись кнопкой "откат" на предпоследней правке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сделать `<div id="b_0"><form></div>`, что не является валидным HTML-кодом. Браузер исправляет ошибку, добавляя `</form>`.

Самый простой вариант создания формы внутри блока `#b_0`:

```js
var html ='<form>';
html += '<input id="dstr" type="text" value="">';
html += '<input id="kstr" type="text" value="">';
html += '<input type="text" id="mta" value = ""/>';
html += '</form>';
$('#b_0').html(html);
```

```html
<div id="b_0"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`type="hidden"` заменён на `type="text"` для наглядности.

---

Чуть более высокоуровневый подход:

```js
var $form = $('<form>');
var $dstr = $('<input>', { id: "dstr", type: "text", value: "" });
var $kstr = $('<input>', { id: "kstr", type: "text", value: "" });
var $mta = $('<input>', { id: "mta", type: "text", value: "" });
$form.append($dstr);
$form.append($kstr);
$form.append($mta);
$('#b_0').html($form);
```

```html
<div id="b_0"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Если `<input>`-ы обязательно должны быть внутри уже существующих `<div id="b_1"></div>` ... `<div id="b_3"></div>`, то эти блоки хотя бы должны быть внутри `<div id="b_0"></div>`:

```js
$("#b_0").wrapInner('<form>');
$("#b_1").html('<input id="dstr" type="text" value="">');
$("#b_2").html('<input id="kstr" type="text" value="">');
$("#b_3").html('<input type="text" id="mta" value = ""/>');
```

```html
<div id="b_0">
    <div id="b_1"></div>
    <div id="b_2"></div>
    <div id="b_3"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Решил задачу!

Comment: @АлексЧе на здоровье. Если ответ вас устраивает, не забудьте отметить его как правильный, нажав на галку в левой верхней части ответа.